# Reverse pagination with Kaminari without paginate_array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, kaminari

I'm a beginner when it comes to ruby on rails. In my project I'm using 'kaminari' gem to paginate collection of images. I would like to reverse the original pagination so instead of:

```
< , 1, 2, 3, 4 ... 10, >
```

*where numbers are page numbers and arrows show prev and next for the pagination view

I want to get:

```
<, 10, 9, 8, 7 ... 1, >
```

My problem is that I can't find any working solution and therefore I'm asking you guys for help. I would like to avoid using paginate_array due to optimization reason. 
Is there a way to simply flip the pagination from right to left? Is something like this even possible with kaminari or should I switch to something else for pagination?

Comment: Do you really need to flip the pagination or do you want the sorted order of images in a different order?  Like newest to oldest?

Comment: you could reverse the array order i.e. **<%= paginate @users.reverse %>**, but m not sure about it

Comment: Anthony - Unfortunately I need to flip it because of the layout that I'm suppose to create. It should have older images on the left, newer on the right.
Jeet - I can't use reverse on the collection if it's not an array.

Comment: You can use sql `order`, `limit`, `offset` and ruby `reverse` in end.

Comment: How could I implement this into code? If you could give me an example that would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql `order`, `limit`, `offset` and ruby `reverse` in end. I try implement some example but need test.

somewhere in model you have method what return page:

```
def users(page)
  # find right offset
  offset = if page.to_i == 1
           # if page number 1 offset be 0 
             0
           elsif page.to_i == 2
           # if page number 2 offset be 10
             10
           else
           # in another case offset must be page * 10
             page.to_i.pred * 10
           end
  # order :desc and reverse
  users.limit(10).offset(offset).order(created_at: :desc).reverse
end
```

`limit` 10 `offset` 0 it is like `page(1).per(10)`
or
`limit` 10 `offset` 10 it is like `page(2).per(10)`.
Try work around this.

Comment: I'll try this out and let you know as soon as possible. Thanks a lot!